# Continuous functor for a Grothendieck topology

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, functors

In MacLane Moerdijk, pag. 393, lemma VII.7.3, the following is stated:

> Let $f:\mathcal{E}\rightarrow\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ be a geometric morphism and $J$ a Grothendieck topology over $\mathbb{C}$, then the following are equivalent:
>
> - $f$ factors through $i:Sh(\mathbb{C},J)\hookrightarrow\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$;
> - $f^*y$ maps covering sieves in $\mathbb{C}$ to colimits in $\mathcal{E}$;
> - $f^*y$ maps covering sieves in $\mathbb{C}$ to epimorphic families in $\mathcal{E}$.
>
> Then $A:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{E}$ is said to be **continuous** for $J$ if $A$ sends covering sieves to colimits/epimorphic families.

I really fail to grasp the concept here, aside from the formal statement: is there any intuition for this notion of continuity? What happens in particular when such a topology is subcanonical?

Comment: You can think of a Grothendieck topology as presenting a topos by "generators and relations": the "generators" are given by the base category, they are generating a category under colimits, and the "relations" are given by the Grothendieck topology, which specifies what the outcome of certain colimits should be.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Could you please give a little more insight? I know that the presheaf category "completes" the base category by adding all possible small colimits, but what does the topology say about that?

Comment: The presheaf category yields the *free* cocompletion: It is cocomplete, but any colimits which might have existed in the base category are destroyed, and the only colimits which exist in the presheaf category exist for very general reasons. Passing to a subcategory of sheaves allows you prescribe that some further diagrams should be colimit diagrams. Briefly, any covering gives rise to a coequalizer diagram. This point of view is spelled out in [this beautiful note of Daniel Dugger](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/cech.pdf), beginning on page 10.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt In that vein, therer is Chapter 8 of [Toposes, Triples, and Theories](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/12/tr12abs.html) on cocone theories. The very beginning of the chapter describes how to turn a sieve into a cocone and the context for the chapter as a whole is [sketches](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sketch).